# Get a users details for a diffrent person

Tags: php, mysql, html

Ok on my website it displays the users friends but it doesn't have their profile picture?

I have 2 databases. One is Users and that is were i save all the users details. the second database has if they are friends in it?

My question is how to get their profile pic from the users table .

p.s. the profile pic row is Proimg

this is my code

Tables

```
In the 2nd database i have the friends details
id Sender Receiver Accepted
1   bob   bill      1
2   fred  bill      3
```

Accepted:

```
1 means that they havent accepted or declined
2 means that they have accepted
3 means that they have declined
```

In the 1st table i have the users details...

```
id Fullname Password proimg    birthday
1   bill     ****     hi.jpg    1991-01-01
2   bob      ****     hello.jpg    1991-07-02
3   fred     ****     hey.jpg    1991-10-05
<?php

    $term = $fullname;
    $sql12 = mysql_query("select * from Friends where Reciver like '%$term%' or Sender like '%$term%'"); 
    $Friends = mysql_num_rows($sql12);

    $t=1;
    while($t<=$Friends)
      {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql12))
        {
      If ($row['accepted'] == 2)
      {
      Echo '<img src="images/defaultprof.png" width="45px" height="45px"/>';   
      }
      else
    {
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    }
    }
      $t++;
    }  
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you show a bit what fields does each table in the database have?

Comment: what type of fields are the `Sender` and `Receiver`? If they are varchar type then i strongly suggest you store user ids from table 1 in them for both users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably want to `INNER JOIN` the user data of the friends. This could be done like this: (based on made up tables ofcourse).

```
SELECT f.*, u.proImg FROM friends AS f 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.userID = f.friendID 
WHERE f.userID = 1;
```

Read entire `JOIN` syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).